How to overcome Scala 3 missing type projection?
In Scala 2 I used type projection in an simple ORM model which contains of IdEntity and some Repositories. Now I tried to migrate to Scala 3 but stuck since type projection with # is missing.
Simplified code looks like:
trait IdEntity:
  type ID_Type
  val id: ID_Type

trait IdLongEntity extends IdEntity:
  override type ID_Type = Long

trait IdStringEntity extends IdEntity:
  override type ID_Type = String

trait IdRepository[E <: IdEnity]:
  def findById(id: E#ID_Type): Option[E]:

Any ideas how to overcome the missing type projection in def findById(id: E#ID_Type)?
I already tried with type match like
object IdEntity:
  type Aux[K] = IdEntity {type ID_Type = K}

type IdType[T <: IdEntity] = T match
    case IdEntity.Aux[k] => k

but this does not work since the compile thinks that the types does not match.
Update:
Thanks to the answer I tried type classes as well as match type but both fail as soon as I try the following (https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UtW9u0mbS5ydiZmQNNWV6g):
trait IdEntity:
  type ID_Type
  val idDefault: ID_Type
  val id: Option[ID_Type]
  def idOrDefault: ID_Type = id.getOrElse(idDefault)

trait IdRepository[E <: IdEntity](using val e: E):
  type ID_Type = e.ID_Type  
  def delete(id: ID_Type): Either[String, Int] = deleteImpl(id)
  def delete(entity: E): Either[String, Int] = delete(entity.idOrDefault) // here the type error occures
  protected def deleteImpl(id: ID_Type): Either[String, Int]


The thing is that E#ID_Type is essentially Any

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/type-projection.html


Indeed, one of the ways is match types:

trait IdEntity:
  type ID_Type
  val id: ID_Type
object IdEntity:
  type Aux[K] = IdEntity {type ID_Type = K}

trait IdLongEntity extends IdEntity:
  override type ID_Type = Long

trait IdStringEntity extends IdEntity:
  override type ID_Type = String

// match type
type IdType[T <: IdEntity] = T match
  case IdEntity.Aux[k] => k

trait IdRepository[E <: IdEntity]:
  def findById(id: IdType[E]): Option[E] = ???

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QoV6Z7xRTOa6hVhAYOb0uw

this does not work since the compile thinks that the types does not match

You should prepare reproduction and we'll see whether compilation can be fixed.

The  other way is type classes:

trait IdEntity:
  type ID_Type
  val id: ID_Type
object IdEntity:
  type Aux[K] = IdEntity {type ID_Type = K}

trait IdLongEntity extends IdEntity:
  override type ID_Type = Long

trait IdStringEntity extends IdEntity:
  override type ID_Type = String

// type class
trait IdType[T <: IdEntity]:
  type Out
object IdType:
  given [K, T <: IdEntity.Aux[K]]: IdType[T] with
    type Out = K

trait IdRepository[E <: IdEntity]:
  def findById(using idType: IdType[E])(id: idType.Out): Option[E] = ???

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/166gIUf3Rg2DwSgLlheXvQ
Or you can even try to use type classes starting from IdEntity, for example making IdEntity a type class:
trait IdEntity:
  type ID_Type
  val id: ID_Type

trait IdLongEntity extends IdEntity:
  override type ID_Type = Long

trait IdStringEntity extends IdEntity:
  override type ID_Type = String

trait IdRepository[E <: IdEntity](using val e: E):
  def findById(id: e.ID_Type): Option[E]

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ap4GJY9NQyOyt2eHwobXSg

In Scala 3, how to replace General Type Projection that has been dropped?
What does Dotty offer to replace type projections?
E is not a legal path since it is not a concrete type (Scala 3)
https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/type-projection.html

Translation of
// scala 2.13, type projections

trait IdEntity {
  type ID_Type
  val idDefault: ID_Type
  val id: Option[ID_Type]
  def idOrDefault: ID_Type = id.getOrElse(idDefault)
}

trait IdRepository[E <: IdEntity] {
  type ID_Type = E#ID_Type
  def delete(id: ID_Type): Either[String, Int] = deleteImpl(id)
  def delete(entity: E): Either[String, Int] = delete(entity.idOrDefault)
  protected def deleteImpl(id: ID_Type): Either[String, Int]
}

can be
// scala 3, match types

trait IdEntity:
  type ID_Type
  val idDefault: ID_Type
  val id: Option[ID_Type]
  def idOrDefault: ID_Type = id.getOrElse(idDefault)
object IdEntity:
  type Aux[K] = IdEntity {type ID_Type = K}

type IdType[T <: IdEntity] = T match
  case IdEntity.Aux[k] => k

// unfortunately, E <: IdEntity.Aux[IdType[E]] doesn't work (match types are not lazy enough): Recursion limit exceeded. Maybe there is an illegal cyclic reference?
trait IdRepository[E <: IdEntity]:
  type ID_Type = IdType[E]
  def delete(id: ID_Type): Either[String, Int] = deleteImpl(id)
  def delete(entity: E {type ID_Type = IdType[E]}): Either[String, Int] = delete(entity.idOrDefault)
  protected def deleteImpl(id: ID_Type): Either[String, Int]

or
// scala 3, type classes (path-dependent types)

trait IdEntity:
  type ID_Type
  val idDefault: ID_Type
  val id: Option[ID_Type]
  def idOrDefault: ID_Type = id.getOrElse(idDefault)

trait IdRepository[E <: IdEntity](using val e: E):
  type ID_Type = e.ID_Type
  def delete(id: ID_Type): Either[String, Int] = deleteImpl(id)
  def delete(entity: E {type ID_Type = e.ID_Type}): Either[String, Int] = delete(entity.idOrDefault)
  protected def deleteImpl(id: ID_Type): Either[String, Int]


Thanks I tried with match type but as soon I have a method def delete(e: E): Unit = delete(e.id) I get a type error that e.id type is e.ID_Type which does not match IdType[E]. Same with type class.

Here i a more detailed code snippet which include the error https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UtW9u0mbS5ydiZmQNNWV6g

Thanks a lot, both attempts are working. Is one better then the other?

@MiNoS No, both are working. Type projections and type classes in Scala 2, match types and type classes in Scala 3, type families and type classes in Haskell. Just different approaches to type-level programming. Both have corner cases. Match types can be tricky on value level, path-dependent types can be tricky.

Now I'm nearly finished but I stuck in a case where I need to 'cast' an instance of E to an instance of E {type ID_Type = IdType[E]} is that possible? I tried TypeTest but could not get it to work.

@MiNoS Please prepare reproduction (maybe starting a new question). On value level there is dependent typing accompanying match types on type level.
